# How to order an array of strings alphabetically after filter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting, methods, filter

I am going through an array , in my VUE app, that has the following structure

```
[
{
  "id": 1,
  "brands": [
    {
      "name": "Mall",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Tanted",
      "id": 25
    },
    {
      "name": "Anteil",
      "id": 12
    },
    {
      "name": "Moscard",
      "id": 73
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "brands": [
    {
      "name": "Yanre",
      "id": 6
    },
    {
      "name": "Alted",
      "id": 10
    },
    {
      "name": "Sillex",
      "id": 9
    },
    {
      "name": "Straf",
      "id": 78
    }
  ]
}
]
```

the first thing I'm doing to show the different options of the select where I show them is a filter by id

```
computed: {
    filteredBrand() {
      var selectedBrand =
        !this.businessInfo || this.businessInfo.selectedBrand == 0
          ? 1
          : this.businessInfo.selectedBrand;
      return !this.$store.getters.brands
        ? null
        : this.$store.getters.brands.filter(
            item => item.id == selectedBrand
          )[0].brands;
    }
}
```

```
              <select
              v-model="businessInfo.selectedBrand"
              @change="onChangeBrand($event)">
              <option v-for="brand in filteredBrand" v-bind:key="brand.name">{{ brand.name }}</option>
              </select>
```

up to this point I manage to show the brands corresponding to each id in the select, but I wanted to sort them also in alphabetical order and I can't find a way to combine the filter with a sort.
I have tried to concatenate the methods but it returns a syntax error.

```
computed: {
    filteredBrand() {
      var selectedBrand =
        !this.businessInfo || this.businessInfo.selectedBrand == 0
          ? 1
          : this.businessInfo.selectedBrand;
      return !this.$store.getters.brands
        ? null
        : this.$store.getters.brands.filter(
            item => item.id == selectedBrand
          )[0].brands.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.name === b.name ? 0 : +(a.name > b.name) || -1;
    });
    }
}
```

How can I do it?
Thank you all for your time and help in advance

Comment: *"but it returns a syntax error"* Please **always** include a copy-and-paste of the actual  complete error message, and tell us what line it's complaining about. I don't see any syntax error in the `sort` code you've shown. (I wouldn't use that code, but I don't see a syntax error in it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare two strings lexicographically (loosely, alphabetically) in ascending order (A-Z), you do this in the `sort` callback:

```
return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
```

For descending order (Z-A), use

```
return b.name.localeCompare(a.name);
```

---

Side note: Any time you find yourself writing `array.filter(/*...*/)[0]`, write `array.find(/*...*/)` instead. *(Polyfilling `find` if you need IE support.)* The [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method stops when it finds the first matching entry and returns that entry, instead of going through the entire array building a new array from all matching entries. You don't need to go through the entire array and build a new one if you're just going to grab the first entry. :-)

So combining that with the main answer above:

```
  return !this.$store.getters.brands
    ? null
    : this.$store.getters.brands.find(
        item => item.id == selectedBrand
      ).brands.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for the perfect explanation. Understood and I hope I don't make the same mistake again! Have a nice day

Comment: just a comment, IE Error in render: "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'find'"

Comment: @javascript110899 - If you need to support IE, you'll need to polyfill `Array.prototype.find`, see the linked MDN page.

Comment: I've just  added the following script to make it work in all browsers <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default,Array.prototype.includes,Array.prototype.find"></script>.
Thank you